# Iterate through taglist in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

According to [taglist definition](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html), the function returns a list of matches.

When I perform something like `:call taglist($func_name)` in vim, it takes me to the first match, presumably.

Is there a command that would open the next match and so on? Or is it needed to write a function for such thing?

Answer (score 0):

> presumably

I'm not sure where you got that from. `:help taglist()` is a function that returns a list without any side-effect so `:call taglist()` is certainly not going to take you to any match.

> Is there a command that would open the next match and so on? Or is it needed to write a function for such thing?

You are looking at the wrong section of the documentation. The right one is `:help tag-matchlist`, where you can read about `:help :tselect`, `:help :tnext`, etc.

The topic is introduced in chapter 29 of `:help user-manual`, *which you shouldn't have skipped*.